# Why does CodePipeline show as failed when all steps passed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline

What causes a CodePipeline to register as failed and why would it register as failed when all component steps succeeded?

[image: Failing CodePipeline]

Comment: Could you add some logs too?

Comment: There are no logs other than the CodeBuild logs showing that the build step runs to completion with no errors and all stages of the CodeBuild process show as successful, as does the overall CodeBuild step. What logs did you have in mind?

Comment: I believe `Link to execution details` should show some details/logs in CloudWatch. Not sure if you investigated that.

Comment: It just links to CodeBuild where the logs finish with `[Container] 2020/09/15 23:08:23 Phase complete: BUILD State: SUCCEEDED`. All phases of CodeBuild show as "SUCCEEDED".

Comment: Seems like `OutputArtifacts` has some issues. FYI `The OutputArtifacts name must match the name of the InputArtifacts in one of its previous stages`

Comment: How do you know that please?

Comment: Did it work for you? I couldn't get any exact document but [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome-introducing-artifacts.html) one could help.

Comment: Generally if we try to update the Pipeline while execution surely it will mark it as failed even though execution for that stage was successful. If this is not the case that means there is some issue between build and codepipeline and in that case retry should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing where the build log showed all phases completed with status SUCCESS. The issue turned out to be a build timeout.

[image]